# ontouchlistener can not work in botton navigation activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, ontouchlistener

i have a botton navigation activity and i want to use a ontouchlistener like :

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    CancelType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.UCancel);

    CancelType.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;

            fragment = new ProvinceFragment();

            if(fragment != null ){
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = 
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.content , fragment );
                ft.commit();
            }

            return false;
        }
    }); 
}
```

when i use this code my app crashed?
 with this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity 
{com.example.mostafa.passenger/com.example.mostafa.passenger.MotelsActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

pls help.

Comment: Please post crash log.

Comment: Update crash log

Comment: Post error log please.